# Geometry, prove that $E$ bisects $\overline{HI}$

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry

Here in the figure, we have:

$\bullet$ The radii of both the circles are equal

$\bullet$ $E$ bisects both $\overline{AC}$ and $\overline{FG}$

$\bullet$ $\overline{HI}$ is a line passing through $E$

**We have to prove that $E$ bisects $\overline{HI}$ as well.**

[image]

(*I think it is really obvious from the figure that's the case but I'm  having a hard time proving it.*)

---

My attempt:

My first attempt was to try to prove that $\triangle AEI\cong\triangle CEH$

I found,

in $\triangle AEI$ and $\triangle CEH$

$\overline{AE}=\overline{EC}$ [$\because$ $E$ bisects $\overline{AC}$]

$\angle AEI=\angle HEC$ [$\because$ vertically opposite angles]

$\overline{AI}=\overline{HC}$ [$\because$ radii of the circles are equal]

*but because these three conditions don't correspond to any congruence criterion, I'm unable to proceed.*

---

I also tried to prove $\angle HCE=\angle EAI$ and hence $\overline{AI}\parallel \overline{HC}$ but failed.

Then I made some constructions which are shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zQxWN.png).

I drew $\angle H'AE=\angle IAE$ and $\angle HCE=\angle I'CE$

That way I was able to prove $\triangle AH'E\cong\triangle AIE$ and  $\triangle HCE\cong\triangle I'CE$

so,

$\overline{H'E}=\overline{IE}$

and

$\overline{HE}=\overline{I'E}$

but again, I'm unable to show that the two pairs are equal.
I'm unable to proceed any further.

---

I'd be very glad if someone could help me prove it.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I'm not sure how you picked points H and I. Did you just pick H and then reflect to find I?

Comment: You have a $180^\circ$ rotational symmetry so $HEI$ is a straight line that is bisected by $E$.

Comment: @CalvinLin Yeah... Thanks. Is it possible to prove the rotational symmetry or is it a proof in itself?

Comment: There's a very slight bit of work in establishing that $E$ is the center of rotation for the 2 circles, namely by showing that "rotate A about E we get C, so the circles rotate onto each other". If this was an entire olympiad problem, I'd establish the rotation. If just using this property as part of a much larger problem, I'd say it's obvious and move on.

Comment: An alternative approach is that you have ASS congruent triangles, where the angle is obtuse (and hence ASS works).

Comment: @Martund When you have an obtuse angle (E.g. $CEH$) with side length $EH$ given, draw a circle of radius $HC$. Then this will intersect line $CE$ at 2 points, but only 1 of them will make $\angle CEH$ an interior angle of the triangle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reflect $H$ along $E$ to get the point $M$. Consider $\triangle AEM$ and $\triangle CEH$, we have,
$$AE=CE\ \ \ (given)\\
EM=EH\ \ \ (by\ \ construction)\\
\angle AEM=\angle CEH\ \ \ (vertically\ \ opposite\ \ angles)$$
Hence, by $SAS$ congruence criterion, we have,
$$\triangle AEM\cong\triangle CEH$$
Therefore,
$$AM=CH$$
Now, since the radii of both the triangles are equal, this means that $M$ lies on the circumference of the left circle, therefore, it is coincident with $I$.

Hence proved